# Migration Matrix in a Two-Dimensional Torus-Like Space: create a migration matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, numerical-methods, markov-chains, random-walk

I'm working on a standard problem in random walk in two dimension.

In particular, I'm trying to generate a migration matrix for a toroidal model (Toroidal Transition Matrix) in R.

I have previously posted the same problem here: [Transition matrix for a two-dimensional random walk in a torus: compute matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786017/transition-matrix-for-a-two-dimensional-random-walk-in-a-torus-compute-matrix-i)

However, I did not get any feedback.

Similarly to what I mentioned in that post, I decided to assume independent movement along each dimension. Therefore, instead of calculating a Toroidal migration matrix and retrieve transition probabilities, I have multiplied independent probabilities from two separate 'one-dimensional circular model'.

I'm not sure whether this is formally correct and I would like to have some opinion on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to walk within the torus with each dimension being independent you do just multiply the transition probabilities.  If there are n states in your circular graph, then there would be n^2 states in your torus and so you should expect a n^2 x n^2 transition matrix.

To give any more detail you'll have to specify exactly what you need to know.